# Can sql server give me a warning if I try and insert unicode without the N prefix

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2012, collation

ok, so the support team have once again updated a value in the database and forgot the N prefix so replaced it with ???s.

Is there something that can be done on either the database (sqlserver 2012) or sqlserver management studio 2012 that can stop or warn people?

And why does the database automagically change the update to ?s, if it's a nvarchar column and I'm passing in Unicode without N why not have it error?

Comment: The database doesn't convert anything automagically. `?` is the replacement character when no conversion is possible. This is typically done at the driver level (ie OLEDB provider or Native Client). If the database threw an error in such cases, you wouldn't be able to *read* rows with such data at all, thus breaking your queries and preventing you from reading other, unaffected columns

Comment: Besides, passing single-byte data (eg. ASCII) to Unicode fields does *not* result in `?`. This appears *only* if you mix up the codepages on the client side, eg. when your conneciton is 1032 (Latin1) but you pass 1033 (Greek) data.

Comment: ah perhaps I wasn't clear I am updating a field to change a Unicode value, e.g. UPDATE table SET column1 = '随机字符中国' WHERE ... but because there's no N the value in the DB becomes ??????

Comment: The point of the N is to indicate that the string value should be considered unicode. When you omit the N what happens is an implicit conversion of the characters to varchar which can't handle the extended ascii characters. It is a syntax issue, not a problem or something that can be "fixed" or "warned" by SSMS.

Comment: yeah I feared that there was nothing that could be done.  As it is a syntax issue I'd hoped it could be made a syntax error with some secret setting. Any sql that is = '随你' has to be an error it can't be what was intended

Comment: What is the collation of the column? You *may* be able to avoid the problem entirely if you use `Tag with column collation when possible=True;Auto Translate=True;` in your connection string. This means that the driver *won't* translate the data from the client to the server codepage, and the collation used *may* be that of the column. If the column uses a Chinese/Japanese collation, you may also be able to avoid conversions. I've never used this combination though and anyway, this should only be done when absolutely necessary

Comment: collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS from when it only had English in but now it's got English, German, Russian and Chinese with more to come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with the driver being used to connect to SQL Server. It is simply an implicit conversion happening due to using the wrong datatype in the string literal. Everything has a type. A number `2` by itself is, by default, an `INT`, and not a `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT` or anything else. A number `2.0` is, by default, a `NUMERIC` (same as `DECIMAL`), and not a `FLOAT`, etc. Strings are no different. A string expressed as `'something'` is 8-bit ASCII, using the Code Page of the database that the query is running in. If you had used `'随机字符中国'` in a database set to one of the collations that supports those characters in an 8-bit encoding (it would be a Double-Byte Character Set (DBCS)) then it would not have translated to `?` since it would have had the character in its Code Page.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [ChineseSimplifiedPinyin] COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_CI_AS;
```

Then, run this:

```sql
USE [ChineseSimplifiedPinyin];
SELECT '随机字符中国';
```

and it will return those characters and *not* `??????`.

> And why does the database automagically change the update to ?s, if it's a nvarchar column and I'm passing in Unicode without N why not have it error?

The `UPDATE` is not being changed. An implicit conversion is happening because you are using the wrong datatype for string literals when not prefixing with the `N`. This is no different than doing the following:

```sql
DECLARE @Test INT;
SET @Test = 2.123;
SELECT @Test;
```

which returns simply a `2`.

Now, it *might* be possible to set up a Policy to trap implicit conversions, but that would be too far reaching and would likely break lots of stuff. Even if you could narrow it down to implicit conversions going from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` that would still break code that would otherwise work in the current situation: inserting `'bob'` into an `NVARCHAR` field would be an implicit conversion yet there would be no data loss. And you can't trap any of this in a Trigger because that is after-the-fact of receiving the implicitly converted data.

The best way to ensure nobody forgets to insert or update without the `N` prefix is to create a web app or console app that would be an interface for this (which is probably a good idea anyway since that will also prevent someone from using the wrong `WHERE` clause or forgetting to use one altogether, both of which do happen). Creating a small .NET web or console app is pretty easy and .NET strings are all Unicode (UTF-16 Little Endian). Then the app takes the data and submits the INSERT or UPDATE statement. Be sure to use a parameter and not dynamic SQL.

---

Given that the `?` character is valid in this field, if it can be determined that multiple `?`s would never naturally occur, then you can probably prevent this issue on cases involving more than a single character getting converted by creating an INSERT, UPDATE Trigger that cancels the operation if multiple `?`s in a row are present. Using a Trigger as opposed to a Check Constraint allows for a little more control, especially over the error message:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_PreventLosingUnicodeCharacters
ON SchemaName.TableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
             FROM   INSERTED ins
             WHERE  ins.column1 LIKE N'%??%')
     )
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK; -- cancel the INSERT or UPDATE operation

    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(1000);
    SET @Message =
               N'INSERT or UPDATE of [column1] without "N" prefix results in data loss. '
                 + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
                 + N'Please try again using N''string'' instead of just ''string''.';

    RAISERROR(@Message, 16, 1);
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
```

And if 2 `?`s can naturally happen, then do the search for `???` and then it is only 1 or 2 character items that might slip by. In either case, this should catch enough erroneous entries so that you only need to fix things on rare occasions (hopefully :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think changing the collation is too big a change for this small problem.  Is there a latin general Unicode collation?

Comment: Also on an app/web page that would safely allow support to change data on any table with transaction protection and proper logging (and no Unicode snafu), it's on the dev list (right at the bottom)

Comment: @dibs487 I was not suggesting that you change the collation. I was just showing that leaving off the `N` did not _always_ result in data loss. Also, I'm not surprised that an app that allows for changing _any_ table, plus logging, is low on the list. It is too lofty of a goal. Just do a small app for just this table and they can add support for more tables as time permits.

Comment: @dibs487 Regarding "Is there a latin general Unicode collation?": All Collations have Unicode support. This is not an issue of Collation but of datatype.

Comment: I like it, I'll have to check on ???, does the replacement character have to be ?

Comment: @dibs487 Yes, the replacement character for "unknown" is always `?`. For the multiple `?`s, just test the current data with something like: `IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE [column1] LIKE N'%??%')) BEGIN PRINT 'Pattern found. Add one more "?"'; END; ELSE BEGIN PRINT 'Score!'; END;` :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something that can be done on either the database (sqlserver 2012) or sqlserver management studio 2012 that can stop or warn people?

Not to my knowledge. About the only thing I can think of would be:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD CONSTRAINT stop_messing_it_up CHECK (NOT column1 LIKE '%?%');
```

but you can't tell the difference between a question mark that came from prior content-mangling and a real question mark, so that would only be workable if it were also invalid to put a question mark in the database.

> why does the database automagically change the update to ?s, if it's a nvarchar column

It doesn't matter what the column is, it's the type of the string literal in the query expression. In SQL Server (only), non-NATIONAL string literals can only contain characters in the locale-specific (“ANSI”) code page, so the data loss occurs before the content gets anywhere near your table:

```
SELECT '随机字符中国';
??????

SELECT N'随机字符中国';
随机字符中国
```

Comment: hmm, like the constraint but unfortunately ? would be perfectly valid in this field.  Still not sure in my head what's doing the conversion Panagiotis Kanavos mentions the driver in his comment.  Does it have to be ?